# Shoe-tying order when tying another's shoes

Tags: halacha, clothing, tying-knots-kosheir, handedness

*Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chayim* 2:4–5:

> ינעול מנעל ימין תחילה ולא יקשרנו ואחר כך ינעול של שמאל ויקשרנו ויחזור ויקשור של ימין
>
> One should don his right shoe first but not tie it, then don his left and tie it, then tie his right.

*Mishna B'rura* explains that we tie the left shoe first

> דלענין קשירה מצינו שהתורה נתנה חשיבות אל השמאל שקושר עליה תפילה של יד
>
> because regarding tying we find that the Torah lends importance to the left, for we tie the hand-*t'filin* there.

He adds that

> ואיטר יד שמניח תפילין בימין של כל אדם יקדים ימין גם להקשירה
>
> a left-handed person who wears *t'filin* on his right should also accord the right precedence for tying.

Thus, a left-handed person ties his right shoe before his left; a right-handed person ties his left shoe before his right.

Suppose a left-handed person is putting and tying shoes on a right-handed person's feet, or vice versa (a right-handed person is doing so on a left-handed person's feet). What order should he do so in?

I'd appreciate any source that discusses this (though [*B'er Moshe* (the Debreciner), volume 2 number 3 section 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=887&pgnum=257), and *Yad Eliezer* (English, [Rabbi Krohn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paysach_Krohn), fifth ed., 1996), section A-14, do not), or arguments in support of either position.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/820

Comment: What about a woman? Or amputee?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard when putting *t'filin* on another person is to put it on a right-handed person's left arm and a left-handed person's right arm irrespective of the handedness of the one putting it on him. Since the order of tying shoes is derived from the arm on which one puts *t'filin*, I propose that it depends on the handedness of the one wearing the shoes and not on the handedness of the one tying them.

But that's based on nothing beyond what little intellect I can lay claim to.