# How to tie shoes on a baby when unsure if righty or lefty

Tags: baby-infant, handedness

There are differences in Halachos regarding a righty verses a lefty in the order of tying shoes. See related question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28639/shoe-tying-order-when-tying-anothers-shoes) for more information on what exactly to do. My question is what about when tying the shoes of someone who we don't know yet whether they are a righty or a lefty such as a baby? Do we say that since most people are righties we should tie them like a righty or does it go by the person tying the shoes?

Comment: Is it halacha that the shoes must be put on in the traditional manner? (Right on first, then left, tie left, tie right.) Besides, aren't infants exempt from many mitzvos?

Comment: I believe that is the halacha. See link in the question where he quotes the Mishna Berurah. Regarding your second comment, you are correct that they are exempt. However there are many instances where we involve children in Halachos such as Netilas yodayim in the morning even though they may be exempt according to the letter of the law.

Comment: The Rama writes that nowadays lefties and righties tie the same

Comment: @ezra It's not even a mitzvah - IIRC, it's an outcome of darchei emori, but there are many circumstances in which it might not apply. Who's left, for instance, are we "going by?" It's the process, not the outcome here, that's the issue (since the shoes will end up being tied the same way) and it's not "derech" to tie ***anyone else's*** shoes. I'd posit that without a source that says otherwise, there's no specific halacha regarding tying another person's shoes.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28639/shoe-tying-order-when-tying-anothers-shoes

Comment: @DoubleAA He's only talking about shoes which don't require tying.

Comment: @Ploni ie "our shoes". Do you have reason to think he's not referring to the normal shoes you see nowadays? Have shoes changed so much in the last 500 years? The Gemara is probably talking about tying something more like a chalitza shoe which resembles tefillin straps (have you ever seen one of those?)

Comment: @DoubleAA The words he uses is "שאין צריכים קשירה". Lace shoes of today still require tying a knot.

Comment: Can't say this as sourced but my mother is adamant that we put on the baby's clothing right side first.

Comment: @Ploni Ok but now step back from your associations of modern footwear with the literal translations that you're expecting and think for a moment. What shoes were they wearing then that didn't tie at all? And what is the expected connection to tefillin? And what does Tosfot mean by ינעול as opposed to יקשור if the placement on the foot isn't at issue? Also take a look at [Roman sandals](http://www.mrcostumes.com/Mens-Roman-Sandals-P101662.aspx) and [Chalitza shoes](http://steinsaltz.org/Halitza_shoe.php) and see if you don't think there's something else going on.